# How did Renaissance bring about a sense of redemption in the Europeans?

Tags: renaissance

I was doing an essay on the topic and I had this idea.

So we always talk about how the Renaissance brought about the Reformation. But never how, in the countries, the people redeemed themselves after centuries of systematic oppression. However, I'm not sure if my train of thought is correct. I'd love to have any and every input and any sources I can read up on specifically how Renaissance brought about a sense of redemption that I can read up in a day.

Comment: In whose eyes are the people to be redeemed? Are you talking about religious redemption or something else?

Comment: @SteveBird i was looking for redemption of every kind . moral, educational, religious and literary redemption and basically all sorts of freedom from every sort of chain.

Comment: Too many undefined terms; insufficient [preliminary research](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/618/why-did-my-question-get-a-downvote?lastactivity); please read our [help] and revise the question to better fit the site.

Comment: Engels’ German Peasants War is a start. And the answer is like the Lollards: “the people” failed. The German settlement on as the prince so the people is clearly indicative of the failure of popular economic liberation.  The prior art of Lollards indicates it isn’t the renaissance but changes in peasant economics (mobilisation capacity) and infantry cavalry balance. Your question is too broad, and confused between intellectual and socioeconomic history.

Comment: It looks to me more like you need a discussion to work your ideas out, rather than having a specific question about history you need answered. Its a discussion I'd *love* to have with you, but the proper venue is probably a nice little dive bar with Negra Modelo on tap, rather than here. The closest such "third place" we have online is our public chat, [The Time Machine](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1560/the-time-machine).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to be very direct, but your train of thought is wrong because it is based on wrong premises.

First wrong premise, there was no special feeling of oppression during the Middle Age: the social order was unequal based on today's criteria, but by the time it *was* justified by practical necessities and religion. And most people, in Europe during the Middle Age, had the faith.

Second wrong premise, Renaisssance liberated people of the oppression: it is wrong because Renaissance was very difficult for "common people" (not for artists on the other hand): numerous wars, political difficulties, a very long change in the conditions of life... Renaissance did not bring freedom nor prosperity in a few years.

So how did the Renaissance bring a sense of redemption?

- Renaissance, contrary to what you seem to imagine, precisely bring the Reform because people start loosing faith in the Church (not in God) because they realized the Pope was a political object for France, the Holy Roman Empire or Charles Quint